# spring mvc annotation - I can not mapping url to controller, Help me, please

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, url-routing

I have .jsp page: index.jsp, that has form with link:

```
<form name="firstForm" method="get" action="list.form">
 //-//-//

         <a href = "removeFromStorage?id=<%=index %>">Remove from storage</a>
 //-//-//

</form>
```

and I have my controller:

```
@Controller

@RequestMapping(value = "/removeFromStorage")

public class MyController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/removeFromStorage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@RequestParam("name") String name, ModelMap model){

    //must get index of order, that must delete
    //int index_remove = new Integer(req.getParameter("index"));


    return "index";//request.getRequestDispatcher("hello.jsp").forward(req,res);
}

}
```

**How can I map controller (MyController) to url (removeFromStorage)?**

**What have I write in annotation of MyController to process url=removeFromStorage from .jsp-page?**

Answer (score 0):

The Controller mapping you have

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/removeFromStorage", method = RequestMethod.GET)value = "/removeFromStorage"
```

declares handling for a GET http request to the path `/removeFromStorage` which is relative to the context of the application. To make your anchor `<a href>` point to `removeFromStorage` relative to the context path, you can change it to:

```
<a href = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/removeFromStorage?id=<%=index %>">Remove from storage</a>
```